# Add "created" timestamp to LOGBOOK

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I would like to change the behavior of `C-c C-x i` so that it creates a "date created" timestamp i.e.

```
** TODO New Task
   :LOGBOOK:
   CREATED: [2016-03-29 Tue 11:41]
   :END:
```

I basically want to log the age of tasks, but I'm not interested in tracking the time spent on a task. Is there a strait forward way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Instead of adding it to the LOGBOOK, it might work better to add it a property.  In particular, it's easier to get the created time out that way.  This function sets a `CREATED` property with the current time in an inactive time stamp.  It will not alter any existing `CREATED` property.

```lisp
(defvar org-created-property-name "CREATED"
  "The name of the org-mode property that stores the creation date of the entry")

(defun org-set-created-property (&optional active NAME)
  "Set a property on the entry giving the creation time.

By default the property is called CREATED. If given the `NAME'
argument will be used instead. If the property already exists, it
will not be modified."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((created (or NAME org-created-property-name))
         (fmt (if active "<%s>" "[%s]"))
         (now  (format fmt (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M"))))
    (unless (org-entry-get (point) created nil)
      (org-set-property created now))))
```

If you're using `org-capture` to create entries, you can call this automatically by adding it to a hook: `(add-hook 'org-capture-before-finalize-hook #'org-set-created-property)`

Comment: I'm a little confused how this works. How would creating a task trigger creating a timestamp item in `:PROPERTIES:`?

Comment: It triggers automatically when you create an entry using `org-capture` (`C-c c`).  Otherwise you can call it manually or hook into whatever functions is creating your entry.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about `org-capture` it seems very powerful.

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this by [tracking TODO state changes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html). Specifically, if you add a timestamp to the `TODO`

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
   '((sequence "TODO(t!)" "WAIT(w@/!)" "|" "DONE(d!)" "CANCELED(c@)")))
```

This will add timestamps (indicated by the `!`) when you create a new TODO, change it to WAIT, or change it to DONE. See the linked manual page for more details.

To get this timestamp entered into your LOGBOOK drawer, you need to set the variable `org-log-into-drawer` to `t` (or the name you want to use for the drawer if it isn't "LOGBOOK").

This will produce the following:

```
** TODO My Task
   :LOGBOOK:
   - State "TODO"       from "NEW"        [2016-01-18 Mon 13:36]
   :END:
   Update stackexchange answer
```

I think this is the closest you can get to the requested `CREATED:` timestamp using orgmodes built-in features. To further change the formatting would require some custom elisp I think.

Comment: Doing that results in something that looks like this `- State "TODO"       from              [2016-03-29 Tue 11:41]` is there an easy way to insert this data into the `:LOGBOOK:` similar to the format I mention in my question?

Comment: Sorry, forgot which of the settings in my config applied to this issue. See the update.

Comment: What do you have `C-c C-x i` bound to, by the way?

Comment: C-c C-x TAB runs the command org-clock-in, which is an interactive
autoloaded Lisp closure in `org-clock.el'.

Comment: Is there a way to change the format of the item on the log book from `- State "TODO"       from "NEW"        [2016-01-18 Mon 13:36]` to simply `[2016-01-18 Mon 13:36]`? Also how can I map this functionality to a key combination?

Comment: If we're talking about a `CREATED:` timestamp, what is the advantage of `: LOGBOOK:` over a `:PROPERTIES:`?